# Create/add a non existing key to mouse

Tags: windows, mouse, button-remapping, mouse-buttons

My Trust GXT 10 mouse, which I use on Windows 7, has 10 buttons so I can modify them to simulate other key presses.

For example, I could put the Button 1 of my mouse to enter <kbd>A</kbd> every time I press it,
then I would go into my game, and under *Options > key mapping > jump* and enter **A**, so every time I press the Button 1 of my mouse it would jump.

But I don't want to have a conflict between games/programs, so I want to assign for example the Button 1 of my mouse to the non-existing `Custom_key_1`. So I go to *Options > key mapping > Jump* and I press the Button 1 of my mouse. `Jump: Custom_key_1` will appear.

Then, in every other game, when I press the Button 1, nothing will happen because this key doesn't exist, so I wouldn't have a conflict.

Is there any program which creates a "virtual button", which I could assign to my configurable mouse buttons?

Comment: You cannot create a new key, but you can try to find and map a key that isn't available on your keyboard and/or not mapped to any function.

Comment: @n.st any tips of how to find a key wich isn't available on my keyboard?

Comment: If the game you want to control supports key combinations, you can select "Combo Key" in the Trust software (that's why I asked for the mouse model) and enter something like Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F12, that isn't likely to be used anywhere else.

Comment: Btw, since you're worried that your mouse button mappings might interfere with other programs, you could set up different modes for gaming and normal work in the Trust software and switch between them.

Comment: @n.st thanks for the idea of getting a key that isnt available on the keyboard, although its not what i first tried to find, it worked well for me: I downloaded Autohotkey and created a script to send the buttons F13 to F24 (these arent avaible on my keyboard) and assigned then to my mouse buttons. Thanks. (should i delete this as its not the correct answer of 'creating a new button' or answer it myself?)

Comment: @Guest you can post your solution and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a new key, but you can try to find and map a key that isn't available on your keyboard and/or not mapped to any function.

If the game you want to control supports key combinations, you can select "Combo Key" in Trust's mouse configuration software and enter something like Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F12, that isn't likely to be used anywhere else.

---

And as you found out yourself, you can use Autohotkey to simulate keys that are not available on your keyboard, so you can assign them to mouse buttons.